# Automatically run tests on ROS build farm for pure cmake project

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, gtest, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm hosting some pure cmake projects [ifopt](http://wiki.ros.org/ifopt) and [towr](http://wiki.ros.org/towr) (not dependent on catkin) on the ROS build farm, for which I generate some unit test in my *CMakeLists.txt* similar to:

```
find_package(GTest)
add_executable(test my_test.cpp)  
target_link_libraries(test ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES} pthread)
add_test(test test)
```

I can run these with `make test` after a non-catkin build, this works fine.

**How can I tell the ROS build farm (which seems to be internally calling  `catkin_make run_tests`) to run that gtest binary as well after building?** [(jenkins-log)](http://build.ros.org/view/Kdev/job/Kdev__ifopt__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/)

I don't want to *catkinize* my  project, which would allow me to use `catkin_add_gtest`. I want to keep allowing the  `cd build && cmake ..` pure cmake build for users that don't have catkin installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296628/automatically-run-tests-on-ros-build-farm-for-pure-cmake-project/) by [Alexander Winkler](https://answers.ros.org/users/33039/alexander-winkler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ros_buildfarm` first [builds a workspace](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/a6bb22952f69b20207b2fd22494fe95dcca15a18/scripts/devel/catkin_make_isolated_and_test.py#L65-L76), then [builds the tests](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/a6bb22952f69b20207b2fd22494fe95dcca15a18/scripts/devel/catkin_make_isolated_and_test.py#L78-L82) and [runs the tests](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/a6bb22952f69b20207b2fd22494fe95dcca15a18/scripts/devel/catkin_make_isolated_and_test.py#L94-L98).

Since `catkin_make_isolated` is used which just passes make targets It relies on the CMake packages to have a `tests` target to build tests as well as a `run_tests` target to run the tests. For a plain CMake package you need to make sure to create these targets and make sure `run_tests` actually runs the tests. As you have already experienced implementing a similar logic as provided by `catkin` to run tests is not straight forward.

A modified version of the `ros_buildfarm` (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/pull/548) used for ROS 2 uses `colcon` instead of `catkin_make_isolated` for build the workspace and running the tests. The "big" difference is that it doesn't rely on a specific custom target to exist but runs the tests by invoking `ctest` instead. That would immediately work for plain CMake package which use CTest. It is unclear though at the moment when or even if the buildfarm for ROS 1 will switch to use this new build tool.

Maybe you can create a `run_tests` target in your CMake package which just invokes `ctest` (just speculating here - haven't tried it)?

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1